# Large File Upload Memory Issue PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, scaling, litespeed

I recently took over a file hosting site (similar to rapidshare, megaupload etc.) and currently averaging about 75k visitors/day. After the migration, we wrote our own system from scratch. It's now time to upgrade the infrastructure and have been toying around with web servers and scaling. Now the issue is that after file upload is complete, the web server is not "flushing" the used-up memory. We uploaded multiple 300MB+ files and before the upload, we had about 3.7G of memory free and after uploading 3 files of 300M each, the memory usage stands at around 1.2G. Initially, we thought it could be apache issue, but upgrading to Litespeed didn't fix it either. Here's the "memory usage" from 'top'

Mem: 4015996k total, 1206036k used, 2809960k free, 114984k buffers

I am scratching my head to figure out how to "flush" the memory used up by the web server or by php during the upload, because this way the system will run out of memory and crash in no time.

Here are my php.ini values:

max_execution_time = 6000
max_input_time = 6000
memory_limit = 2048M
post_max_size = 2047M
upload_max_filesize = 2047M

On Apache, php runs on fcgi and on Litespeed, it's Litespeed SAPI.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out that it is the "cache memory" and I am able to free it up by this command:
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

MemTotal:        4015996 kB
MemFree:         2490780 kB
Buffers:          118232 kB
Cached:          1204168 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           358748 kB
Inactive:         991220 kB
Active(anon):      28024 kB
Inactive(anon):        0 kB
Active(file):     330724 kB
Inactive(file):   991220 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:       3179664 kB
HighFree:        1918528 kB
LowTotal:         836332 kB
LowFree:          572252 kB
SwapTotal:      48827384 kB
SwapFree:       48827384 kB